# Getting the first bunch on numbers from an array in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Ok, so i got an array which has `[23.0, 24.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]` inside how do i pick the `23.0` out of there?

Comment: Do you get these values as a string?

Comment: Edited question it's an array

Comment: The question was much more interesting when it was string :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
'23.4 24.0 0 0 0 0'[0..3]
```

returns 23.4

you can use split, if you have a variable length

```
'15000 24.0 0 0 0'.split(' ')[0]
```

or match:

```
'23.4 0 0 0 0'.match(/[\d\.]+/)
'23.4 0 0 0 0'.match(/(.*?) /)[1]
```

Comment: undefined method `match' for 0.0:Float and undefined method `split' for 0.0:Float, is there a diffrent method for floats?

Comment: I assumed that your variable contains a string. What is the type?

Comment: from an array you simply use `your_array[0]` to get the first value

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean when dealing with String values? You can index strings, as if they were arrays, using a range.

```
 > numbers = "23.0 24.0 0.0 0.0 0.0"
 > first_four = numbers[0..3]
=> "23.0"

 > numbers = "12500 0 0 0"
 > first_four = numbers[0..3]
=> "1250"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"23.0 24.0 5 2 ".split()[0]
```

Also works for any other value seperated by spaces.